# Switch through Textboxes Automatically After reaching Max Length

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am wondering if there is anyway to simulate exactly what happens when you type a PaysSafeCard pin. The PaySafeCard pin has 4 Textboxes and they are each 4 numbers long. Each one of them when filled, automatically tabs to the next one. All i want to do is do that in vb.net so I don't have to manually press Tab every time. I gave it some thought but i cannot find the command that checks if the Textbox has reached its maxLength so it Tabs to the next one.
Hopefully i made myself understandable :| , thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of broad, but I'm kind of bored.

Yes, you can check the length of the TextBox.Text property each time it is changed. Use the `TextChanged` event. If the length is >= 4, you want to move to the next TextBox.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If TextBox1.Text.Length >= 4 Then TextBox2.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    If TextBox2.Text.Length >= 4 Then TextBox3.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged
    If TextBox3.Text.Length >= 4 Then TextBox4.Focus()
End Sub
```

In my example there are 4 TextBoxes, numbered 1 to 4. It is a bit hard-coded but it works for just 4 TextBoxes.

This also adds a nice feel, so if you enter a TextBox which already has text, it will be selected.

```
Private Sub TextBox_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Enter, TextBox2.Enter, TextBox3.Enter, TextBox4.Enter
    DirectCast(sender, TextBox).SelectAll()
End Sub
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `In my example there are 4 TextBoxes, numbered 1 to 4.`, I see only three... ;)

Comment: OP can handle TextBox4 appropriately. `automatically tabs to the next one` is undefined for number 4